# Is a upright tuple a valid notation?

Tags: notation

Usually a tuple is written like $(x, y, z)$, e.g. like
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\argmax}{argmax}
a*, b*, c*
= \argmax_{a,b,c}( \dotso\text{long line}\dotso ).
$$

For my publication I don't have space for a long tuple like that in the line. So I would like to write:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a* \\ b* \\ c*
\end{pmatrix}
= \argmax_{a,b,c}( \dotso\text{long line}\dotso ).
$$

Is it valid notation to write a tuple upright like that?

Would it also be valid to change
$$
f(x | a,b,c)
$$
into
$$
f\left(x\ \left|\ \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix} \right.\right)?
$$

Comment: It seems to me that you can write however you like, just so long as you make the meaning plain.

Comment: @saulspatz: Maybe a stupid question, but do you have any reference? I haven't seen an upright tuple anywhere so far.

Comment: No I don't have a reference, but I don't think it matters.  Make a definition and use it.  You've never seen an upright tuple?  What about a column vector?

Comment: Do you mean '$\mathrm{argmax}$' (the point at which the maximum is attained) rather than '$\max$' (the maximum value)?

Comment: @OscarCunningham: Yes, I mean argmax, I'll correct it.

Comment: You can use any notation you like.  Of course, it is best to use standard notation when possible, and necessary to define non-standard notation when you use it.  You say that this is for a publication---as such, this is really a question for your editor / reviewers / publisher.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, by a very useful convention, the vector $(a,b,c)$ is identified with the column matrix (or column vector) \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\ \end{bmatrix}

Unfortunately, many people nowadays think that matrices should be delineated with parentheses, not brackets. Consequently, they think that $(a,b,c)$ is a row vector (or row matrix), so they write $(a,b,c)^T$ to mean the above ordinary column vector, to avoid extravagant use of vertical space.

Since you have the opposite problem, with plenty of vertical space but restricted horizontal space, I commend to you the traditional convention, using nice straight matrix brackets, as in the display above, to denote your vector $(a,b,c)$ .

Comment: I see what you mean. But please note, that I do not have a vector, but a tuple, which are two very different mathematical objects. I am not sure if your observations, as useful they are for vectors, can be applied in the same way to tuples. For example, in my case, $a*$ is a real values, $b*$ is a real coordinate space vector, and $c*$ is a real matrix.